# Discrete signals - Z Transforms

Tags: discrete-signals, z-transform

If a system has transfer function $H(z) = 1 + z^{–1} + z^{–2}$, then for an input signal of the sequence = {1,2,3,1,4,-2, 4} calculate the output sequence of the system.

DO i put transfer function into z trandform?

Answer (score 2):

You simply solve by computing it into a table.

Please note the Transfer Function in Z Transform with polynomials of $1$, $z^{-1}$ and $z^{-2}$ are no more than discrete time step delays of t=0, 1 and 2 from the original signal, which are all added into a single expression.

That is, the $z$ is an "add one step time" operator.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solving the problem with Octave/MATLAB code:

x = [1,2,3,1,4,-2,4];
B = [1,1,1];   % H(z) coefficients
A = [1];
Output = filter(B,A,x)